# Restricted weighted OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, weighted-least-squares

I would like to run a restricted weighted OLS regression in R. Let me first state the problem mathematically:

$\arg\min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i} \lvert y_{i} - \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{i,k} \beta_{k}\rvert^{2}$ or in vector notation

$\arg\min_{\beta} \lvert\lvert W^{1/2}(y-X\beta)\rvert\rvert^{2}$

such that

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i} = 1$,

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i} x_{i,k} = 0 \quad \text{for} \; k = 1,\dots,m$,

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i} x_{i,k}^{2} = 1 \quad \text{for} \; k = 1,\dots,m$

To provide an example, following R-code with $i = 10$ and $m = 3$ can be used:

```
y <- rnorm(10)
w <- c(0.05, 0.15, 0.02, 0.08, 0.2, 0.04, 0.06, 0.1, 0.18, 0.12)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
data <- cbind(y, x1, x2, x3, w)
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, weigths = w)
```

That is to say, that I would like to add the constraints that the weights must sum up to one, the `weighted mean` has to be zero and the `weighted standard deviation` has to be one to the regression. The first condition can actually be discarded since the weights do always add up to one in my case. Does anybody know either the mathematical solution (that can later be programmed into R) or a function that is able to perform that directly in R?

Comment: also what is $w_i$ in your notation ? Is $W$ diagonal ?

Comment: also you are optimizing with respect to $\beta$ or $W $ ? the constraints are all in terms of $W$, this means that the constraints are useless !!!!

Comment: I am optimizing with respect to $\beta$, $W$ are the weights. It is a diagonal matrix. Example: $diag \pmatrix{w_{1} \\ w_{2} \\ \vdots \\ w_{n}}$.

Comment: You are saying that the constraints are useless, but do you see a way to incorporate them into the issue (considering the task i want to perform)? Standard weigthed OLS would give the solution $\hat{\beta} = (X^{\top}WX)^{-1}X^{T}Wy$. Somehow I need to incorporate the restrictions. Because of the restrictions, $(X^{\top}WX)^{-1}$ should have ones in the diagonal (because std is 1) and 0 in the first column and line (because weighted mean is 0). You know what I mean?